# Scheduled Incremental Crawl does not work

Tags: 2010, search-results, enterprise-search, incremental-crawl

I have scheduled an incremental crawl in my SharePoint Farm for a website. After every 10 minutes I have scheduled it to run but the new contents are never crawled and indexed as they are not displayed in search results.

But manual incremental crawl works perfect and I can see new contents coming up in search results. What is causing scheduled incremental crawl to fail crawling and indexing contents?

Comment: What's in the crawl logs?

Comment: There are no errors in crawl log

Comment: OK, what successes are you seeing?? Are other items in the target site being crawled?